# Adobe DISPATCH_METHOD for disabling navigation bar, bookmark and right click etc (MFC)

Tags: c++, mfc, adobe, activex, dispatch

I am very new to activeX control and I need to embed adobe activex control in my MFC dialog. 
I use the example code in https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9537/Adobe-ActiveX-Control-with-MFC to implement an Adobe ActiveX control, it works and display the pdf file successfully.

I need the pdf to be displayed without toolbar, navigation bar, bookmark and right click, but the sample code only contains a method like following:
[image]

It works for disabling toolbar. But there is no method for navigation bar etc.
I searched online for `InvokeHelper(0x3, DISPATCH_METHOD, VT_EMPTY, nullptr, parms, On);` and realize that `0x3` is the DISPATCH ID and it is invoking the Adobe API by this ID.
Therefore, I guess there must be other method in Adobe for navigation bar and bookmark etc, but I cannot find the corresponding document about the method DISPATCH ID.

Anyone knows that please ?

I even cannot find any documents about the `setShowToolBar` method DISPATCH ID.

Comment: Have you considered, that there may be *no way* to do that, except changing the code of the component you use? Seems like that may be the case here.

Comment: @JesperJuhl If I use IwebBrowser2 to display the pdf, I can disable the navigation and bookmark and toolbar by passing the command in the url, so I guess Adobe also has that kind of API.. Just guess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By reading `Interapplication Communication API reference` from Adobe, I find out how to close the bookmark automaticlly.

I called `SetPageMode(L"none")`, it works for closing bookmark.
But I haven't figured out how to close the navigation bar and status bar.
[image]